# How to update value in array of object in useState hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am new to `React Hooks`. I have an `state` which looks like this.

```
const [myData, setmyData] = useState([
    {
        "OrderId": "ord-898s1",
        "Shoulder Size": "12",
        "Amount": 200,
        "Shoulder Width": "2",
       
    },
{
        "OrderId": "ord-898s2",
        "Shoulder Size": "14",
        "Amount": 790,
        "Shoulder Width": "2",
       
    }
])
var orderID = "ord-898s2"
var AmountToAdd = 100
```

I want to update the `Amount` Value in orderID `ord-898s2`. By adding `100`, the Amount Value in orderID `ord-898s2` should be `890`

```
console.log(myData)
```

Required Output:

```
[
    {
        "OrderId": "ord-898s1",
        "Shoulder Size": "12",
        "Amount": 200,
        "Shoulder Width": "2",

    },
{
        "OrderId": "ord-898s2",
        "Shoulder Size": "14",
        "Amount": 890,
        "Shoulder Width": "2",

    }
]
```

I tried these.

```
 const result2 = myData.map((item) => {
        if (item.OrderId === orderID) {
        
            return { ...item, ["Amount"]:item.Amount +100  }
         

        }
        
        return item
      })
     setmyData(result2)
```

it failed. I don't know how to make it. Please help me with some solutions.

Comment: Your `.map()` logic should work, what makes you think it's failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
    setmyData((prev) =>
      prev.map((el) =>
        el.OrderId === "ord-898s2" ? { ...el, Amount: el.Amount + 100 } : el
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```js
var data = [
    {
        "OrderId": "ord-898s1",
        "Shoulder Size": "12",
        "Amount": 200,
        "Shoulder Width": "2",
       
    },
{
        "OrderId": "ord-898s2",
        "Shoulder Size": "14",
        "Amount": 790,
        "Shoulder Width": "2",
       
    }
];

var orderID = "ord-898s2"
var AmountToAdd = 100

data.forEach((item) =>
  item.OrderId === orderID ? item.Amount = item.Amount + AmountToAdd : item.Amount);
  
 console.log(data);
```